# What format is shown in gdb's output for a binary std::vector?

Tags: c++

I have a std::vector object in the debugger.  Not sure if it matters, but I'm using Eclipse CDT.  The watch output includes the data which looks like this: `7ýj%\035&.ÄÂSC\001j\002J:ìT;zC¢\b¿f¼\200d\rÿ\212ÈÕ*ä­u`

Notice: Most of the \ are preceded by exactally 3 numbers. the \n is an exception (probably a new line char)

It appears to be partially encoded using the back slashes.  So, I would like to take this string hopefully using the clipboard then use Linux to convert in into binary information.  From there other conversions are straightforward.

Do you know what this format is?

Comment: Then it is eclipse or `gdb` adding the escape sequences?  Thank you, I improved the title.

Comment: @PaulEvans It's raw binary output as if it were text.

Comment: Well, how would a "string view" of control characters be done?  How is the debugger supposed to represent a form feed, or a vertical tab, or even an embedded NULL?  You're using the wrong tool here.  What you probably need is some sort of "Memory View".  Never using Eclipse, see if there is such a view, where you can inspect the memory.

Comment: Great, I am using the memory view and getting better data... That is going to work.  It did not result in any new cool `gdb` commands though.  http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_memory.htm